# Could Not Find Gem, but Gem is Installed without Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

Whenever I run the rails server or the specs, I get this error:

`Could not find debugger-1.6.8 in any of the sources`

When I run `gem install debugger`, it works just fine:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed debugger-1.6.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for debugger-1.6.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-1.6.8...
(eval):5: warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /\[a-z]+/
```

but the bundler list doesn't show debugger-1.6.8:

```
* daemons (1.2.3)
* delayed_job (4.0.3)
* delayed_job_active_record (4.1.0)
* diff-lcs (1.2.5)
* domain_name (0.5.25)
* double-bag-ftps (0.1.2)
```

I also don't have a `.bundle/config` file that is preventing any gems from being installed.

Here is my Gemfile with the :test and :development group:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.9'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.2'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'awesome_print', '1.2.0'
  gem 'debugger', platform: :mri_19
  gem 'byebug' if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0.0'
end
```

When i remove the platform specification, i get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am running ruby 1.9.3-p551 with rbenv.

How do I get the debugger gem installed into the project bundle so I can run my server and tests?

Comment: have you checked the Gemfile?

Comment: Added some clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-install your `bundler gem` and `rbenv` (via brew). Sometimes these installations can go bad, and the permissions on your machine will be sad when bundler and rbenv go to set your gems.

Comment: This may not be a direct solution to my problem, but in a round about way it led to my problem being fixed